# When I update my database schema with drush entity-updates. I get an error

Tags: database, drush, ubercart, updating

When I try to update my database Schema I'm getting the following error:

> Drupal\Core\Entity\Exception\FieldStorageDefinitionUpdateForbiddenException:[error]
>   The SQL storage cannot change the schema for an existing field
>   (order_total in uc_order entity) with data. in
>   Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorageSchema->updateSharedTableSchema()
>   (line 1376 of
>   /www/htdocs/xxx/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorageSchema.php).
>   Failed:                                                              [error]
>   Drupal\Core\Entity\Exception\FieldStorageDefinitionUpdateForbiddenException:
>   !message in
>   Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorageSchema->updateSharedTableSchema()
>   (line 1376 of
>   /www/htdocs/xxx/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorageSchema.php).

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are trying to update existing field order_total in uc_order. You can't update it since you have some data in it already. Remove content that uses it (orders), and try again.

Also note that drush entity:updates currently doesn't support all changes (e.g. changing table keys). See this Change Record for information on providing a hook_update(): https://www.drupal.org/node/2554097

Comment: I checked if there is any orders and I couldn't find any...

Comment: I went to the database and deleted the entries there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you been using ubercart for Drupal 8? There is a good chance give it's an alpha that there is no upgrade path. Using it in production at this stage could possibly cause issues when the schema for entities and tables change. Deleting the data on a production site might not always be an option.

If the data isn't relevant, a good way to "chase HEAD", that is follow the code when no upgrade path is available is to build sites as an install profile and regularly update your configuration objects as schema changes. [Here is a blog post](https://codedrop.com.au/blog/test-driving-drupal-8-writing-install-profile) from a year or so before D8 was released which has some info about reinstalling to chase schema updates. [More info on install profiles](https://www.drupal.org/node/2210443).